# StateNotifier's state

Tags: flutter, dart, provider, riverpod, flutter-riverpod

I'm a newbie in Riverpod and currently I'm trying to use StateNotifierProvider for my cart screen
and I wonder is there any way while incrementing or decrementing cart items I can change the specific quantity variable in CartModel
and update state to show changes in quantity in cart screen

```
final cartListProvider2 =   
StateNotifierProvider.autoDispose<CartList2,
AsyncValue<buyingOptionModel.BuyingOptionsModel>>((ref) {
return CartList2(); //init empty cart
});

class CartList2 extends 
StateNotifier<AsyncValue<buyingOptionModel.BuyingOptionsModel>> 
{
 CartList2() : super(AsyncValue.loading()) {
 _getData();
}

void _getData() async {

final json = await 
ProductRepository().buyingOptions(product_id: 11361);
var data = buyingOptionModel.BuyingOptionsModel.fromJson(json);
state = await AsyncValue.guard(() async => await data);
}

void increment(int index) async {
 state.value!.pricing![index].quantity =
    state.value!.pricing![index].quantity! +
        state.value!.pricing![index].moq!;

state == state ? print("same") : print("different");
}

void decrement(int index) async {}
```

}

Comment: Do you mean specifically are *you* able?  How can we possibly answer that?  :)  But yes, what you're saying is possible with some code.  Show some code, and we can be more specific.

Comment: I have given code please guide me.